# FB_Ignited not returning $fb->me

Tags: php, facebook, api, codeigniter

I can get FB_Ignited to work with the demo provided, but whenever I try it from the landing page of my site, it:

1. hits the Auth controller
2. goes to FB
3. comes back to the Auth controller and loads the 'start' view, while passing $content_data

For some reason, on the start view, $this->fb_me isn't available.

Here's my Auth controller - this is hit when the FB button is hit from the landing page

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();      

    $this->load->library('fb_ignited');
    // The fb_ignited library is already auto-loaded so call the user and app.
    $this->fb_me = $this->fb_ignited->fb_get_me();      
    $this->fb_app = $this->fb_ignited->fb_get_app();

    // This is a Request System I made to be used to work with Facebook Ignited.
    // NOTE: This is not mandatory for the system to work.
    if ($this->input->get('request_ids'))
    {
        $requests = $this->input->get('request_ids');
        $this->request_result = $this->fb_ignited->fb_accept_requests($requests);
    }
}

function index($type="")
{   
    if (isset($this->request_result)) {
        $content_data['error'] = $this->request_result;
    } 

    if ($this->fb_me) {
        $content_data['me'] = $this->fb_me;
    } 

    $this->load->model('users');
    $checkandadd = $this->users->checkandadd($this->fb_me);

    $this->load->view('start', $content_data);
}
```

}

Not sure if it'll help, but here is what $this->facebook outputs (IDs and hashes intentionally tweaked):

```
Facebook Object
(
    [appId:protected] => 123456123456123456
    [apiSecret:protected] => 123456123456123456
    [user:protected] => 0
    [signedRequest:protected] => 
    [state:protected] => 123456123456123456
    [accessToken:protected] => 123456123456123456|123456123456123456
    [fileUploadSupport:protected] => 
)
```

Some other notes:

- `*RECURSION*` shows up a few times whenever I print_r($this->fb_ignited)
- Nothing shows up in the error logs

Anyone encounter something like this before?

Comment: Have you tried making sure that the library was autoloaded? Also what version of Facebook Ignited are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of [Facebook Ignited](https://github.com/Necromnius/Facebook-Ignited/) you will find that I have taken care of that issue for people that do not have query strings enabled as well as user info not being loaded because I am using the latest Facebook PHP SDK. I suggest you upgrade to [v1.1.2](https://github.com/Necromnius/Facebook-Ignited/downloads) which you can download with minimal changes to your CodeIgniter application.

Comment: Thank you for you reply!! Sorry it took me so long, got caught up with other stuff. Cheers!